# Get 'Column Title' from EnumerableRowCollection<T> LINQ Results

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, ienumerable

Hopefully this is relatively simple.  After I perform a `LINQ` query on a `DataTable` I want to put the results in a another `DataTable` which I plan to create dynamically.  What I need is to find the name of th `column titles` in the `LINQ` Query reults collection.

**EDIT**: The LINQ Query

```
var results= from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where a.Field<int>("ID") == i 
                    select new 
                    {
                       ID = a.Field<int>("ID"),
                       a = a.Field<double>("A"),
                       b = a.Field<double>("B")
                    };
```

I am basically trying to return - "ID", "a", and "b".

Really hope that makes sense!

Comment: You just need to return a list of column names from a data table?

Comment: no from the results of my LINQ query.

Comment: What is your LINQ query? Show please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since query results set is a set of anonymous type items you can NOT do anything in terms of DataTable and DataColumn/Rows... But you can retrieve names using reflection since each column will be represented as public property of the anonymous type:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = results.First()
                                   .GetType()
                                   .GetProperties()
                                   .Select(p => p.Name);
```

This would return:

```
[0]: "ID"
[1]: "a"
[2]: "b"
```

Comment: do not forget to add `if (results != null and results.Count() > 0)`

Answer (score -1):

As a quick knock-up (probably not the best but this was done in a hurry - a big hurry!!):

```
    Dim _dt As New DataTable
    Dim _col1 As New DataColumn("ClientID", GetType(Integer))
    Dim _col2 As New DataColumn("ClientName", GetType(String))

    _dt.Columns.Add(_col1)
    _dt.Columns.Add(_col2)

    _dt.Rows.Add(1, "John")
    _dt.Rows.Add(2, "Shaun")

    Dim _query = From dt In _dt

    Dim _colName As New List(Of String)

    For Each _q In _query
        For Each _column In _q.Table.Columns
            _colName.Add(_column.ToString)
        Next
    Next
```

Or if you already have a linq query in place, convert it back to a data table then get the columns:

```
    Dim _dt1 = _query.CopyToDataTable

    For Each _column In _dt1.Columns
        _colName.Add(_column.ToString)
    Next
```

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Doesnt this just return the DataTable column titles, rather than the queries "column titles"?

Comment: The CopyToDataTable() method doenst work.  I seem to remeber its something to do with it being Enumerable (or not, or something!)

Comment: Just looked at your query and as it is an anonymous type being returned. @sll has provided the correct answer below!